# What is the best way to update state using useReducer function hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a list with the following actions:

1. **Add** an Object into an array using `useReducer()` function.
2. **Remove** an Object from an array using `useReducer()` function.
3. **Replace** new array with old array using `useReducer()`
   function.

I need the best and safe way to update my list.

Currently I have done something like below, but it is not working properly.

```
const reducer = (state, {type, value}) => {
    switch(type){
        case 'replacenewarray':
            return value;
        case 'additem':
            return {...state, value}
        case 'removeitem':
            return state.filter(item => item.room !== value);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

My functional component is as below:

```
const newArray = [
     {room: 'someroomid1', ....},
     {room: 'someroomid2', ....},
     {room: 'someroomid3', ....}
];

const itemToAdd = {room: 'someroomid4', ....};
const itemToRemoveWithRoomId = 'someroomid2';

export const Group = memo(props=> {

    const [list, setList] = useReducer(reducer, []);

    setList({type: 'replacenewarray', value: newArray});
    setList({type: 'additem', value: itemToAdd});
    setList({type: 'removeitem', value: itemToRemoveWithRoomId});


});
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing with this code?

Comment: I would declare the shape of the state somewhere in the reducer so it helps to understand more the code, also I would follow the example from here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your code, your state is an `Array`, make sure you preserve the type when returning it from `useReducer`:

```
const reducer = (state, { type, value }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'replacenewarray':
//             v Array as intended
      return value;
    case 'additem':
//             v Fix it to return an array
      return [...state, value];
//             v Object
//    return {...state, value}
    case 'removeitem':
//             v Array as intended
      return state.filter(item => item.room !== value);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Also, you must return a `ReactElement` or `Group` will not be considered as **functional-component**.

```
export const Group = memo(props => {
  ...
  return <>Some React Element</>;
});
```

Comment: I can't guess how you read the `list` and how your application is structured, moreover you using `React.memo`, there is a chance your component not even rendered after `dispatch`